# Converting an Excel Formual to SQL

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql

I have a formula in Excel that calculates how many Sundays are between two dates but I want to do the same in SQL, but cannot figure out how to do it. Can you help?

```
=SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(A1-8,1)+B1-A1)/7))

Declare @From as Datetime 
Declare @To as Datetime 

Set @From = '7 Jan 2013' 
Set @To = '18 Mar 2013' 

SELECT SUM(WEEKDATE(@From-8,1)+ @End-@From)/7)) AS No_Of_Sundays 
FROM TIME
```

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @From) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + DATEDIFF(dd, @From, @To) / 7) AS No_Of_Sundays
```

As you see, it depends on localization -> in Russia Sunday is day#7 so we do a check if the first day is sunday

Here's another solution:

```
Declare @From as Datetime 
Declare @To as Datetime 
Declare @sundays as INT

Set @From = '1/02/2013' 
Set @To = '28/02/2013' 
Set @sundays = 0

WHILE (@From <= @To)
BEGIN
    SET @sundays = @sundays + (CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, @From) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    SET @From = DATEADD(dd, 1, @From)
END

SELECT @sundays
```

Comment: Hi Sergio, something is wrong because it isn't counting all Sundays, for example in February there are 4 but the SQL is counting 3

Comment: I am getting this error message: 
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Use localized datetime format as '7 Jan 2013' or '02/01/2013'. In Russia day goes first, in us/uk month is first in a date :)

Comment: Nearly - in the UK the day is first.

Comment: London is a capital of Great Britain, and date format is mm/dd/yyyy, that's all i know about UK :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sql-server 2005 or above, this is a method using `CTE`. Here is a **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9935)**

```
declare @From date = '20130107' --'7 Jan 2013' 
declare @To date = '20130318'  --'18 Mar 2013' 

;with CTE as (
  select 0 number , datename(weekday, @from) dName
  union all
  select number+1, datename(weekday,dateadd(day,number+1,@from)) dName
  from CTE 
  where dateadd(day, number + 1,@from) <= @to and
       datename(weekday,dateadd(day,number,@from)) <> 'sunday'
)

select top(1) (datediff(day,@from,@to) - number )/7 + 
               case when number = 0 and dname <> 'sunday' then 0 else 1 end
               sundays
from CTE
order by number desc
```