# Using an amemded @From and @To date to get a new result

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my criteria for the SQL below:

From Date 07 Jan 2013 To Date 18 Mar 2013

1 - First Sunday After 07 Jan 2013 is 13 Jan 2013 - Done (FirstSunday)
2 - First Sunday Before 18 Mar 2013 is 17 Mar 2013 - Done (LastSunday)
3 - How many days between 13 Jan 2013 and 17 Mar 2013 = 63, Divide 63 by 7 = 9, +1 = 10

So what I need my datediff to do is use the results from the 1st and 2nd rows above (First and Last Sundays date) so I get the correct result for section 3. Can you help?

```
Declare @From Datetime
Declare @To Datetime

Set @From = '07 Jan 2013'
Set @To = '18 Mar 2013'

Select dateadd(dd, CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, @From) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 8 - datepart(weekday, @From) END,@From) as FirstSunday, 
dateadd(dd, CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, @To) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 - datepart(weekday, @To) END,@To) as LastSunday

,datediff(d,@From, @To)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd actually set down the overall objective first, and then how you're currently trying to solve it. I think it's something along the lines of "I need to find the whole number of weeks between two dates (rounding up any fractional part), where weeks are considered to start on a Sunday", but I'm not entirely sure of that translation.

Comment: Hi Damien
I want to count how many Sundays there are between two dates, as you can see I have the firstsunday after the @From Date and the LastSunday before the to Date. However when I use the date diff function to to get the amount of days and divide they by 7 I get the wrong answer because the datediff is using the original From and To dates and not the dates from my select statement

Comment: And if either of those dates are a Sunday, should they be in- or ex- cluded?

Comment: I remember I answered almost [similar question from you here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131692/converting-an-excel-formual-to-sql/15133263#15133263)

Comment: Excluded because I will add +1 and the end of the datediff query

datediff(d,@From, @To)/7)+1

Comment: It seems like just doing `DATEDIFF(week,@From,@To)` is remarkably close to answering your question, depending on how you answer my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Kaf

I read that yesterday but I have no idea what CTE is and it seemed a bit much for this query, but I maybe wrong because I am very new to SQl

Comment: `CTE` is for [`COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) I am finding `first sunday from @from date inside the CTE`. I think that is what you looking for

Comment: Hi Damien

Thanks for that I didn't even think to use the 'week within datediff' But it only works in a fashion. I am still getting wrong results for example if I do 1st Dec 2013 to 31st Dec 2013 the result should be 5 but I get 4 and this is because is its not counting the first sunday, however if I add +1 to the statement this makes Jan and a whole load of months wrong then. Thoughts?

Comment: Believe or not, [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131692/converting-an-excel-formual-to-sql/15133263#15133263) is more elegant, efficient and optimised than looping and it is `NOT too much`.

Comment: I don't doubt it Kaf, but I have been asked to do it this way. Sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25355/discussion-between-kaf-and-wafw1971)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps:

```
Declare @From  Datetime 
Declare @To  Datetime 
Declare @temp  Datetime 
Declare @firstSunday DateTime
Declare @lastSunday DateTime

Set @From = '7 Jan 2013' 
Set @To = '18 Mar 2013'


set @temp = @From
WHILE ( @temp <= @To )
    BEGIN 
        IF DATEPART(dw, @temp) = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @firstSunday = @temp
            BREAK
        END

        set @temp = dateadd(dd,1,@temp)

    END


set @temp = @To
WHILE ( @temp >= @From )
    BEGIN

    IF DATEPART(dw, @temp) = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @lastSunday = @temp
            BREAK
        END

        set @temp = dateadd(dd,-1,@temp)

    END

SELECT @firstSunday, @lastSunday, DATEDIFF(dd,@firstSunday, @lastSunday)/7 +1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @From Datetime
Declare @To Datetime

Set @From = '01 Mar 2013'
Set @To = '31 Mar 2013'


SELECT Datediff(Week, dateadd(dd, CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, @From) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 8 - datepart(weekday, @From) END,@From), 
dateadd(dd, CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, @To) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 - datepart(weekday, @To) END,@To))+1
```

Comment: fyi: this is not guaranteed to work in a another machine with diff culture due to different first day of week in different cultures.

Comment: Hi Kaf

You are right of course, but at the moment its what I need. But thank you for all your help.

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more elegant but *less* readable than [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131692/converting-an-excel-formual-to-sql)

[**Fiddle demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10119)

```
declare @From date = '20130107' --'7 Jan 2013' 
declare @To date = '20130318'  --'18 Mar 2013' 

select datediff(day,dateadd(day,wkdays,@from),@to)/7 + 
       case when wkdays = 0 and 
        datename(weekday,dateadd(day,wkdays,@from)) <> 'sunday' then 0 else 1 end 
from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(wkdays)
where dateadd(day,wkdays,@from) between @from and @to
      and datename(weekday,dateadd(day,wkdays,@from)) = 'sunday'
```